# web2py write in lowercase in UPEERCASE field

Tags: web2py

i've got a " requires = IS_UPPER()" field in my table, i need to sometimes write in lowercase, there is a way to do that?
I have tried to use html quote or unicode tag but without any results.
Thank you

Comment: If you need to write in lowercase then just don't use the `IS_UPPER()` validator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the validator conditionally:

```
if some_condition:
    db.mytable.myfield.requires = None # or some other validator
```